# How to draw a circle with WebGL using GL_POINTS

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm trying to draw a circle using simple vertices points and a big gl_PointSize value. I found [this example](http://gamedusa.blogspot.fr/2007/05/drawing-circle-primitives-using.html) and try to reproduce it on WebGL with no success.

Comment: We need more information. What goes wrong? What did you try?

Comment: Here is an example http://codepen.io/moechofe/pen/ezgFb
It seems my problem is my program doesn't compile when I add the varying variable.

Comment: I forgot to add "precision mediump float;" in my fragment shader

Comment: For anyone looking for the same solution checkout https://blog.scottlogic.com/2019/10/17/sculpting-shapes-with-webgl-fragment-shader.html . Using this method its possible, using gl.POINTS, to calculate the distance of a point pixel from its centre(gl_PointCoord) and discard or alter its ALPHA channel to create circles or any shape from a single gl.POINT, without using triangles or point arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just using regular old sine and cosine to step around the circumference of a circle and place points. You just need to know the center of the circle, the radius and how many points you want. The following pseudo code will output a set of points that make up the positions of dots you need to make a circle of points:

```
circleXY(Vector3f center, float radius, int dots) {
    float stepSize = ((2*Math.PI)/dots);
    for (float d = 0; d <= (2*Math.PI)-stepSize; d += stepSize) {
      addPoint(((sin(d) * radius) + center.x),
                (cos(d) * radius) + center.y));
    }
    return result;
}
```

You will have to modify it to fit your language and APIs. But, if you know how to draw a point, you can easily utilize this to know where to draw them.